# Rotate arrow according to linestring direction in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

I want to rotate an arrow according to a line string direction (route) in OpenLayers.

Can someone explain me how it works.

[Click here for demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/feature-move-animation-forked-rvde10?file=/main.js)

I want to set coordinates and set arrow direction according to the coordinates.

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: Demo does exactly what you want to do. What is not clear there?

Comment: @TomazicM i want to set my coordinates and set blue arrow image rotating according to our coordinates.

Comment: But that's exactly what's done in demo. What's not clear there?

Comment: @TomazicM in demo you take another data and set rotation on this route

Comment: What do you mean by "another data set"? Please edit your question, add your existing relevant code and explain in detail what you want to do, otherwise question is most likely to be closed, as were your three previous ones.

Answer (score 1):

Where you are choosing a random point instead of a distance along the line obtaining the segment for the angle will need to be done differently.  Make sure the point is on the LineString by calling `.getClosestPoint()`.  In about 5% of cases this is not accurate enough, so calling it twice may help.  Then find the segment that intersects that point. https://codesandbox.io/s/feature-move-animation-forked-scrcdi?file=/main.js